# Should a table name contain a descriptor if it is always true?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am creating a table [Request] that temporarily stores a row, to be used an hour later. At that time the row is removed.

Basically we are only storing requests that are still open.

My question is, should it be named [OpenRequest], or just [Request] with a [Status] column that is always 'open'?

Current design idea for the table:

```
Request:
    CorrelationId (primary key)
    GroupId (unique key, not null)
    CreationTimestamp (index, not null)
    AuthApplication (not null)
    IncidentId (nullable)
```

Comment: What is the `` character meant to represent?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't suggest deleting the data, at least not if you are going to need it again (and you say now you won't, but one day, you will; perhaps for an audit, or because request was "fulfilled" when in actuallity it wasn't). `Status` is the right way to go, and have your application/SQL filter the data appropriately.

Comment: I second this comment.   Unless business requirements *forcibly* require you to do otherwise, it'd be almost simpler to have a Request table with a status column (maybe you might have open/closed items later), rather than an [OpenRequest] and [ClosedRequest] table (in the future), and worry about coding extra lines to move data between.

Comment: I apologize, the {} character was a mistake of copy/pasting. 

I believe that keeping the records in there for some extended amount of time, and track the Status. I think your reasoning will help greatly in convincing our teams architect of this change. Thank you.

Comment: The only time I would suggest you would need to delete the rows is to fulfil regulatory requirements. For example, someone exercising the right to be forgotten and can be deleted without failing other (regulatory/business) requirements, or the data falls outside of your company's retention policy. And that *assumes* you are storing personal data.